# How can I get the roots of a polynomial?

Tags: java, arrays, function, polynomial-math

I have a polynomial,for example **`3x`<sup>`4`</sup>`- 5x + 4`**.

Assume that I have an array `A = { 3, 0, 0, -5, 4 }` with the polynomial's coefficients.

How can I use the array `A` to find the roots of the polynomial?

Is there any function or library to download to do it?

[**Note:** Original question was about a quadratic: **`3x`<sup>`2`</sup>`- 5x + 4`**.]

I found this:  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/solvers/LaguerreSolver.html

How can I get the roots of the polynomial and store them in a an array B?...

Comment: it is pretty easy algorithm - why not try to code it yourself?

Comment: Can't you write the Quadratic Equation formula?

Comment: Why did you edit the equation to be order 8? That will have a completely different solution technique.

Comment: Because that's what I want. I want to solve polynomial of all orders, not only quadratic...

Answer (score 2):

For **ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c = 0** the solutions are

**x = (-b + (b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac)<sup>1/2</sup>) / 2a**

and

**x = (-b - (b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac)<sup>1/2</sup>) / 2a**

By the way, there are analytical solutions up to and including the 4<sup>th</sup> degree.

Comment: [Note that I answered this before OP edited the order of the polynomial to 8]

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical Java libraries:

[colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/),
[Apache's Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/),
[JScience](http://jscience.org/)

to list just a three of them. But you probably don't need a library to solve such a trivial equation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [efficient java matrix library](http://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/wiki/PolynomialRootExample)

They have a sample code in the same link.